# How to share selection rectangle between multiple NSCollectionViews?

Tags: cocoa, event-handling, nscollectionview

I am building an app, which will draw a representation of column-based data. I need both interactable cells and headers, so instead of adding suppplementary views for each column, I made another NSCollectionView that contains headers only.
The issue is that I would like to share selection rectangle state between these collection views, but I am not sure if there's some good way to achieve that or I have to hack whole controller.

Initially I was thinking about making an overlay on whole window, that would register in first responder chain, but it would use methods like draggedMouse only in my own methods and I would override built-in to pass the events to views behind, then if the view detected that user would like to draw a selection rectangle (select multiple items), that event would be moved to overlay view.

I thought also about making first row of items as sections (I am using compositional collection view layout, so it isn't that hard), but I think it would make features like drag and drop a huge pain in the bottom.

On the image you can see part of these collection views and how it looks now.
[image: Cursor that started dragging in one view and has been dragged over to another NSCollectionView]

Comment: Have you considered one collection view with extra header items?

Comment: I did, sadly it doesn't provide enough features I want it to have (selection states, drag and drop). Also I had an issue, where scrolled items were over the header view, so I changed header's zPosition, but it made selection rectangle drawing below the header. Lowering sections' position also was quite bugged with drag and drop.